# azure databricks autoloader with structure streaming

Tags: azure, databricks

We are facing an issue with reading and writing streaming data into the target location.

we are working with some JSON telemetry data for tracking steps. New data files land in our delta lake every 5 seconds. Need a way that automatically ingests into delta lake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
    query = (spark.readStream
                  .format("cloudFiles")
                  .option("cloudFiles.format", "json")
                  .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", <schemaLocation>)
                  .load(<dataset_source>)
                  .writeStream
                  .format("delta")
                  .option("checkpointLocation", <checkpoint_path>)
                  .trigger(processingTime="<Provide the time>")
                  .outputMode("append") # you can use complete if needed
                  .table("table_name"))
```

For more info refer: https://docs.databricks.com/ingestion/auto-loader/index.html

Comment: Thank you for the update. but I want to read a particular subfolders. Do you have any idea.

Comment: Provide the appropriate folder path in ```load("folder_path")```, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to read particular sub folder. For  **Example**: This is my file location  `/mnt/2023/01/13` .I am want to read `2023/01` inside data, then load data like this`load('/mnt/<folder>/<sub_folder>')` or `/mnt/2023/*`

```
query = (spark.readStream
                  .format("cloudFiles")
                  .option("cloudFiles.format", "json")
                  .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", <Location>)
                  .load('/mnt/<folder>/<sub_folder>')
```